Refresh field value without reload page
I'm currelty work in symfony 7 application with messenger. I would like to update entity field value in a handler. The handler is working in async. I would like the people in the page not need to reload page for update value. Is this possible ?
My handler is async and i consume message with the command "php bin/console messenger:consume async"
Thank you.
My handler async :
    public function __invoke(StatusMessage $message)
    {
        $path = $message->getFileName();

        $entity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Messages::class)->findOneBy([
            'id' => $message->getId(),
        ]);

        if ($entity) {
            // change status to 'processed'
            $entity->setStatus('processed');
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }

    }


Why are you using messenger for this? IMO, You are using the wrong tool. For that simple operation, simply put that code in a controller action and call it via javascript to update your page w/o reloading.
